# Ableton: Record everything I do and play it back on-screen

Tags: ableton

Is there a way to have Ableton record everything I do -- where I click, what I adjust, etc so that I can watch myself later?  The best way to do this might be to simply record a video of my screen using some screen recording software.

But if I wanted to record my movements in Ableton every time I jam with it as a kind of learning archive for myself, I would quickly have terabytes of video.  So is there a way to just record my interactions (a la Windows 3.1 Macro Recorder) and play them back?

Comment: This is a sweet idea. There is probably a way to do (some of) this using Max/MSP. To clarify: most of this can be accomplished by capturing MIDI data, but not all. Are you including the act of adding/removing effects, tracks, or changing the signal path (Audio From / Audio To), and other things that may not be accomplishable via MIDI?

Comment: Furthermore Quicktime includes a screen and audio capture device, if you do wind up going for the video route.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature like this in Live.

The closest thing I can think of is arming all tracks for recording, and capturing all audio, MIDI, and parameter movements (as automation). You'll be able to generally hear what happened and see what device parameters were changed, but you won't have a visual display of where your mouse moved, what windows you had opened, any menus you went into, and you won't be able to edit on the Arrangement while it's recording.